# custom raw compression

Tags: raw, image-compression

I'm planning to acquire between 50k and 200k image per day with a 50MPixels (or 68MPixels or 130MPixels) sensor; I'll be acquiring the raw data (10 or 12 or 14 bits) from the sensor through SLVS-EC and create a raw file of my own design. The raw bitrate from the sensor may go up to 75.2 Gbps.

I may have to store 50k-250k images per day (eg., 17.5TB if 250k images are 70MB-50MPixels each). I need to keep high quality images (in particular, colors must remain accurate and textures fully detailed, hence the lossless or only light loss and nothing below 10 bits per channel), and a flexibility in edition (hence the raw).

Also images will share a lot, since I may have 2-24Hz framerate at capture; also a first processing will drop (delete) between 10% and 50% of images, so a keyframe based compression may not be suitable.

Since I need to keep the storage cost as low as possible without doing too hard compression (maybe go below 30-50MB per raw image). I'm planning to allow compression within this raw file, this compression can be lossless or lightly lossy. I'm thinking about wavelet and auto learnt dictionaries (patchs and sparse coding) for the compression, but this is not a requirement.

I will not release any sdk or raw image, so there are no need or requirement on the standard and adoption side. I'll very likely use an FPGA for signal processing (up to 75.2Gbps from the sensor), since I need very high IO and fast signal processing, and the whole package will be embedded, and as compact as possible and reasonnably light (say less than 1-2kg).

About the images, it will be natural environment with natural day light; it may include shadows and sky with sun, and hence high dynamic, but also rich (high frequency) textures which must be preserved. So likely I won't add further denoising, but I want to keep the fexibility with color processing: in particular the ability to change the signal amplification and the white/black balance.

Do you have thoughts and pieces of advice about the compression strategy for this raw format ? In particular do you think video compression algorithms (eg., HEVC) could be adapted to raw bayered data ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not exactly about photography but about compression algorithms.

Comment: Yes, it just feels like the wrong "forum" to me. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says that "Photography Stack Exchange is for professional, enthusiast and amateur photographers", whereas this question is very much more towards the "engineering" side of image capture / image processing.

Comment: It feels to me like it would be a better fit for Signal Processing, judging by their on topic list - https://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I don't see the point of creating yet another raw format.  It just makes using the images more difficult because no existing software will be able to interpret it.

Comment: "24Hz framerate at capture" – aka, [video](https://video.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @xiota I'm building my own camera, and my own softwares so I'll have what I need on that side. I cannot and won't use existing proprietary formats. When I define everything myself I have maximum flexibility.

Comment: @xiota Well, I need images to be independant (no key frame) and there is no real timing or timecode and zero sound. Any timelapse is a video from a point of view.

Comment: "won't use existing proprietary formats" – That's the problem DNG is supposed to solve.  It has compression support, and you can use existing libraries.

Comment: @xiota The DNG point is excellent and one of the rare on-topic comments among comments and answers. DNG does not fall in the proprietary format in the sense that specifications and implementations are open or available freely without justification.

Comment: You ask for "thoughts and advice", so pretty much *everything* is "on topic".  If you just want a vanity raw format and compression algorithm, have at it.  Since you say you plan not to release anything related to it, there's really no point.

Comment: @xiota I'm asking thoughts and pieces of advice about compression for raw data and that's it. Nothing about if I'm right or wrong, if there is a point or not, or about planning, nothing about proprietary formats or hardware and so on.

Comment: "... thoughts and pieces of advice about compression for raw data..." includes whether developing a new format is advisable, planning, etc.  If you don't want others' input, what's the point of posting in a public forum?  As for proprietary formats and hardware, you introduced those topics. So if going "off topic" bothers you, why not adhere to your own standard?

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing or why.  For instance, you've repeatedly rejected key frame algorithms, yet you mention methods that commonly involve keyframes.  Then in an edit, you ask "in particular" about adapting keyframe (video) algorithms to your project.

Comment: Developing compression algorithms isn't something photographers are expected to know.  Photographers use existing formats and algorithms.  So in a forum of photographers, a natural question would be why there isn't a suitable existing format or algorithm.  The proliferation of raw formats has been harmful to photographers (lost images).  So the motivation for the creation of yet another one is relevant.  The efficiency of compression algorithms also depends on the data being compressed.  A lot more information about your project would be needed to determine suitable methods.

Comment: @xiota Before the last paragraph I describe the kind of image which will be comrpessed. About the keyframe based compression, I'll be dropping a significant amount of images, and it may not be relevant, unless dropping an image is actually not so costly, unless I find a way to reencode quickly the sequence after dropping images, or if I have something like a *master dictionary of patches*, which makes sense for wavelet compression, and in that case I may have most of the cost going into the dictionary and very little into an individual image; and we could refer to the dictionary as key image.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about producing still photographs as described in this community's guidelines. Per the OP it is about "... thoughts and pieces of advice about compression for raw data and that's it."

Comment: I would recommend starting out by testing available lossless compressions. By my experience you may achieve about 3x reduction in size.
Beyond that you need lossy compression, or maybe you might have a specific image that allows for greater compression, but I doubt that.

Answer (score 0):

A raw format is already compressed, so don't expect too much gain with lossless compression. For instance the Canon format derives from TIFF and likely uses LZW compression; the raw files from my camera are about half the size you would expect (Pixel count × 3 × bit depth).

If you use lossy compression, you would have to check the effects on demosaicing algorithms.

Storage is cheap.

---

Edit:

In your case, the problem won't be storage, but I/O bandwidth... 18TB/day is around 200MB/s. Given the size I assume this will not be on local disks... 200MB/s sustained requires a dedicated I/O architecture, likely tape libraries somewhere (plural, because backup). Source: I worked on the digital video infrastructure for a large TV channel (4TB/day of video intake).

Of course you can compress by a factor of two, but you'll have to find an algorithm that doesn't burn too much CPU (and you still have to manage a 200MB/s intake bandwidth, and enough CPUs...).

You should also wonder about the output bandwidth (because all this data will be used at some point). In the video infrastructure described above, it was estimated that each input (write) was read 3.75 times in its lifespan. This is another I/O bandwidth to take in account.

Finally, what kind of data center you have in the end to process/use all these images?

Comment: I'm creating my own raw format, so no: I'll have to compress it myself. With 18TB per day of images, storage is critical, so is compression.

Comment: See augmented answer

Comment: Well, no, bandwidth is not the question, I'll have an FPGA for the sensor readout processing and an SSD sata RAID array to sustain >1GB/s for writing (OP updated) since nvme is still expensive.

Comment: The data center is kind of off topic. But it will be 10Gbit ethernet and an 18/20TB based NAS, with FPGA.

Comment: From personal experience: don't believe figures, do real benchmarks...

Comment: Well, you are indeed free to choose not to believe in planning and mathematics... In my experience, my predictions are accurate and useful. For IO, however, there are many things happening so the mean bitrate is just a mean and an indication. NVMes for instance are not working continously, instead they execute very short and very fast bursts with very high IO and most of the time are not doing any IO.

Comment: "A raw format is already compressed, so don't expect too much gain with lossless compression." This is wrong. The raw data is not compressed, I'm designing my own raw format (likely based on HEIC), and the compression can be significan (eg., about 1/18 with redcode or prores raw).

Comment: There is definitely **lossless** compression is commercial raw files.

Comment: Yes, both lossless and lossy, but I'm talking about the **raw data from the sensor**.

Comment: "the raw files from my camera are about half the size you would expect (Pixel count × 3 × bit depth)." Ummm... Canon raw files (and pretty much everyone else's when Bayer masked sensors are used) have a single monochrome luminance value per photosite (a/k/a pixel well - only digitally stored images have pixels). No need to multiply bit-depth by three, since there is only one 14-bit value per photosite.

Answer (score 0):

Don't.

Entire companies, industries, standards, and fortunes are bought and sold upon what you want to do.

There's a reason H.266 is expensive in processing power- squeezing that little bit more out is computationally expensive for little gain.

Storage is cheap (as was said). Buy 2x what you need, and keep a copy.

Comment: With 18TB per day of images, storage is critical, so is compression.